# How do I resolve Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop while setting a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am getting an object `location` from another page like this.

```
const location = useLocation();
```

I am trying to set a variable like this.

```
if (location.state !== null) {
  console.log(location.state.name.companyName)
  setcompanyOneAlready(location.state.name.companyName);
  console.log(companyOneAlready);
}
```

But this results in a "Too many renders" error. I realize it's because of the way I am setting `companyOneAlready` but I don't know how to correct this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a functional or class based component? Share your full component code that way it will be easy to help you.

Comment: add `&& location.state.name.companyName !== companyOneAlready)` to your if statement to prevent re-setting the value if it is already set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are running the code as an unintentional side effect and the condition is malformed.

Use the `useEffect` hook with correct dependencies to issue the side-effect to update state.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (location.state !== null) {
    setcompanyOneAlready(location.state.name.companyName);
  }
}, [location.state]);
```

To help save a rerender you can also check the current `companyOneAlready` value prior to enqueueing the state update.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (location.state?.name?.companyName !== companyOneAlready) {
    setcompanyOneAlready(location.state.name.companyName);
  }
}, [location.state, companyOneAlready]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `location.state` is never null. I believe by default it is an empty object and `{} !== null` is always true. Also, I assume that `setcompanyOneAlready` changes the state in the component. That triggers rerender and your's condition will be true on every render. That's the reason why you get the mentioned error.

You should put this condition inside useEffect and useEffect should have a `name` or `companyName` in the dependency array to rerun the effect only when some of these values are changed.